Runtime error after upgrading to .NET Standard 2.0
I have upgraded a Visual Studio project from .NET Framework 4.6.2 to .NET Standard 2.0 using Upgrade Assistant. The project is part of a large solution with many projects (.net Framework 4.6.2) that have references to the upgraded Standard 2.0 project. An example of that is a test project that is running tests on the upgraded project. The solution builds ok. Running a test results in an error message:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=8.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
Why is that, and why the System.ServiceModel.xxx dlls is not present in the bin folder of any of the projects .net Framework 4.6.2? Do I have to change anything on the 4.6.2 projects to make it work?
Tried true in csproj-file on both projects. On the upgraded project the System.ServiceModel.xxx dlls then appear in the bin folder, but not in the .net Framework project.
The plan is to upgrade all project, first to Standard 2.0, then to latest version of .net core. But it is a large solution, and have to do one project at a time.

You don't "upgrade" to .NET Standard. That's a cross-platform API specification, not a runtime. It can only be used to create libraries. WCF isn't part of that spec. The error you posted points to a missing NuGet package

What are you trying to do in the first place, and why switch from .NET Framework to .NET Standard 2.0? Microsoft itself never migrated WCF to .NET (Core). . Tools like dotnet svcutil or Visual Studio's Add Connected Service can generate SOAP clients for .NET (Core). To create SOAP services, you'd need CoreWCF, a community project. If you want to create a library that's usable in both .NET Framework and .NET (Core) you need to add the necessary WCF NuGet packages to your library.

Yes, I upgrade, using Upgrade Assistant, to .NET Standard 2.0. This is why:
"if you want to share code between .NET Framework and any other .NET implementation, such as .NET Core, your library should target .NET Standard 2.0".
Ref.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0

No you didn't upgrade. The link you posted doesn't say what you assumed. .NET Standard 2.0 isn't a "new" version, it's a subset of 4.6.2 APIs that's common with .NET Core. That subset doesn't include WCF namespaces like System.ServiceModel. You have to install the missing classes using the relevant NuGet packages. The error message already says you need to install System.ServiceModel.Primitives. If you click on the link in this comment (and the first comment) you'll see this is available as a NuGet package

As for The plan is to upgrade all project, first to Standard 2.0, then to latest version of .net core. this won't help, precisely because .NET Standard is a subset of .NET Framework. Many of the missing APIs were added in .NET 5 and 6, but as I said, WCF was never migrated. If you migrate to .NET Standard 2.0 you'll face problems that were solved later on.  The oldest supported .NET version is .NET 8, so try to upgrade to it directly

I tried, but here is the error message, so your suggestion wont work:
Project xxx.csproj targets net8.0. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.

You didn't say you want to use the library in .NET Framework 4.6.2 as well. If you need .NET Standard 2.0, add the missing packages
